# Matplotlib: How to adjust linewidth in colorbar for contour plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's a minimal example to generate a plot which illustrates my question:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.mpl as mpl
import numpy as np
import random

data = [[random.random() for i in range(10)] for j in range(10)]

[XT, YT] = np.meshgrid(np.arange(1,10+1,1), np.arange(1,10+1,1))

cmap = mpl.cm.gray

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

CS = ax.contour(XT, YT, data,levels=np.arange(0,1+0.1,0.1),\
                cmap=cmap,linewidths=0.75)
CB = plt.colorbar(CS, ticks=np.arange(0,1+0.1,0.1))  

plt.show()
```

The resulting figure looks like this:

[image: gray_contours]

I would like to keep the `linewidths` of the contour lines in the figure at `0.75` but increase them in the `colorbar` (for better readability).

How do I change the `linewidths` in the `colorbar` without changing them in the figure?

I initially tried `CB.collections`, but the `colorbar` has no `collections`. Also, calling `colorbar` with an argument `linewidths=4.0` does not work (it's an unknown parameter).

**Comment**
While typing this question I had this idea ([rubber duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)):

```
CS = ax.contour(XT, YT, data,levels=np.arange(0,1+0.1,0.1),\
            cmap=cmap,linewidths=4.0)
CB = plt.colorbar(CS, ticks=np.arange(0,1+0.1,0.1))
plt.setp(CS.collections , linewidth=0.75)
```

Basically, setting the initial `linewidths` to the desired level for the `colorbar`, then generating the `colorbar` and afterwards using `collections` on the original contour-lines to decrease their linewidth.
This works.

**But:** Is there a way to directly control the `linewidths` in the `colorbar`?

Comment: if adding `linewidths=4.0` to colorbar didn't work, then there probably isn't a clean way (and a very quick glance at the code seems to confirm this).  See `colorbar.ColorBar.add_lines`.  It seems to be designed to explicitly _follow_ the line widths in the contour plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to find out how to access those lines, let try:

```
>>> CB.ax.get_children()
[<matplotlib.axis.XAxis object at 0x026A74B0>, <matplotlib.axis.YAxis object at 0x026AF270>, <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x026AF190>, <matplotlib.patches.Polygon object at 0x027387F0>, <matplotlib.collections.LineCollection object at 0x02748BD0>, <matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x026C0D10>, <matplotlib.patches.Rectangle object at 0x026C0D50>, <matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x026A7410>, <matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x026A7290>, <matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x026A7350>, <matplotlib.spines.Spine object at 0x026A71B0>]
```

Alright, take a guess, I bet the 5th item is a list of the divider lines. We are looking for some `.line` objects and there are two. The first one (3rd item) actually is the edge of the entire color bar (if I remember correctly). So I will go for the next `.line` object.

Now let's try to modified it in a few ways:

```
>>> len(lines1[4].get_linewidths())
11 #how many item are there? 11 lines
>>> lines1[4].set_color(['r']*11) #set them all to red, in this example we actually want to have the color stay the same, this is just for a demonstration. 
>>> lines1[4].set_linewidths([2]*11) #set them all to have linewidth of 2.
```

the result[image]

Comment: Ah, try `get_children()` instead of `get_childern()` and see if that helps.

Comment: That typo is on me, sorry. It works. I have condensed it to this command: `CB.ax.get_children()[4].set_linewidths(5.0)`.

Comment: To change the edging lines of the palette: CB.ax.get_children()[2].set_linewidths(5.0)

Comment: `set_linewidths` (in plural) does not work for me but this does: `CB.lines[0].set_linewidth(5.0)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `Axes.tick_params`.
As you use `CB` as the handle to the colorbar, the linewidth in colorbar can be set by:

```
CB.ax.tick_params(size = your_size, width = your_width)
```

`size` is the length of ticklines in the colorbar. `width` is the linewidth.